# Why do mouseover events not work for all states in d3.js projection?

Tags: d3.js, mouseover

I'm having some difficulty understanding why mouseover events are occuring inconsistently in my projection.  I'm looking to highlight a state on mouseover, which works most of the time, but for certain states the mouseover event does not occur at all. Can anyone help me understand what the problem is here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/topojson-client@3"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        const width = 1000;
        const height = 600;

        const path = d3.geoPath(null);

        const svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("width", width)
            .style("display", "block")
            .style("margin", "auto");

        d3.json("https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json").then(data => {
            svg.selectAll(".states")
                .data(topojson.feature(data, data.objects.states).features)
                .join("path")
                .attr("d", path)
                .style("fill", "none")
                .attr("class", "states")
                .style("stroke", "black")
                .style("stroke-width", "2px")
                .style("cursor", "pointer")
                .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
                    d3.select(this)
                        .transition(100)
                        .style("fill", "#6d7899");
                })
                .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
                    d3.select(this)
                        .transition(100)
                        .style("fill", "none");
                });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to identify the source of the problem.  You must have the "fill" attribute set to an actual value, rather than "none", for the mouseover event to properly recognize the geographical boundaries in the projection.